# How can I return int and string attributes in a single Java method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I would like to return the values of all the attributes from the `BaseballPlayer` class. The method that needs to do this must be the public string `getBaseballPlayer(int i)` method (because I need to reference this method inside `getBaseballPlayers()` to return all the values as an arraylist of strings) I'm having trouble doing this because all the attributes have different datatypes (`int`, `String`, `Height`).

I've tried doing this:

```
public String getBaseballPlayer(int i){

ArrayList <String> bArray = new ArrayList <String>();  
    bArray.add(getHometown());
    bArray.add(getState());                       
    bArray.add(getHighSchool());
    bArray.add(getPosition());
```

However, it only works for the string methods, and doesn't necessarily return the actual values but rather the get methods for each string attribute.

```
public class BaseballPlayer extends Player implements Table {    

  private int num;
  private String pos;

public BaseballPlayer( int a, String b, String c, int d, 
String e, String f, String g, Height h){


        super(a,ft,in,c,d,e,f,ht);
        num = a;
        pos = b; 

}

public BaseballPlayer(){}


//Returns the value of a specific attribute. The input parameter start 
  with 0 for the first attribute, then 1 for the second attribute and so 
  on.
//you can use getBaseballPlayer(int i) in getBaseballPlayers( ) with a for 
  loop getting each getBaseballPlayer(int i).


public String getBaseballPlayer(int i){

ArrayList <String> bArray = new ArrayList <String>();  
    bArray.add(getHometown());
    bArray.add(getState());                       
    bArray.add(getHighSchool());
    bArray.add(getPosition());
    return (bArray);    
}

//Returns the value of all attributes as an ArrayList of Strings.
public ArrayList <String> getBaseballPlayers(){
}
```

I'm just looking for the simplest way to return each attributes value, then using that method return each value as an arraylist of strings in another method.

Comment: Simplest option IMO would be to wrap them in an object, and return that!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to return the whole object as one String. Unless and otherwise, you are forced to do this, do not try and do.

Well, if your requirement can't be changed, and if you want everything from the Baseball object to be in one string, you can concatenate all the parameters with a delimiter like ":".

Eg:

```
public String getBaseballPlayer(int i){
    return getHometown() + ":" + getState() + ":" +getHighSchool() + ":" + getPosition();
}
```

On the invoking side, you can get the individual values from this String using "split()" method of String.

Comment: I didn't downvote but shouldn't you be using `i` somewhere?

Comment: Hello @GBlodgett. The question gives just a rough idea of what is required. It will not even compile. So, I just wanted to paint the same picture so that the person who asked can understand easily. I seriously don't know why someone must downvote the question as well as the answer. I have clearly mentioned that its not a good practice to return everything as String. But if his requirements can't be changed at all, then no choice. We should provide an way to get achieve it. :)

Comment: Many would argue that if the question only gives a rough idea of what is required (i.e. the requirements are unclear) that the questioned should be closed and not answered. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions) thread about that discussion

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that @GBlodgett. Am new here. So probably I need to learn the trade before answering. Anyways, it is mentioned that if there is a good answer for bad question, it shouldn't be down-voted. Following which the answer shouldn't be downvoted. Anyways, since it wasn't you, you can't do anything about it. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't let a downvote bother you. If you keep making helpful contributions you'll get upvotes and reputation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, if you want to do it perfectly, is what [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is for. It rides on top of simple JSON and can encode arbitrary classes, data structures, and other types into JSON such that you can reconstruct those objects easily from the JSON representation.  It's easy to use considering how powerful what it does really is.

It's even easier to use regular JSON if you don't need to encode types that JSON won't handle by itself.  In your case, it seems that this could be good enough.  The great thing about JSON is that it's a standard.  You don't have to choose an encoding scheme, and you already have libraries written in any language you can think of that can read your String'ified data.

Here's an example that roughly follows what your code is doing:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

public class BaseballPlayer {

    private String name;
    private String hometown;
    private String state;
    private int age;
    private double height;
    private String position;

    static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public BaseballPlayer( String name, String hometown, String state, int age, double height, String position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hometown = hometown;
        this.state = state;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setHometown(String hometown) {
        this.hometown = hometown;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setHeight(float height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s from %s, %s (height: %.1f)", name, hometown, state, height);
    }

    public BaseballPlayer(){}

    // Turn a BaseballPlayer object into a String
    public String getAsJSON() {
        Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
        info.put("name", name);
        info.put("hometown", hometown);
        info.put("state", state);
        info.put("age", age);
        info.put("height", height);
        info.put("position", position);

        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(info);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Here's the method you ask for.  I don't know what 'i' is supposed
    // to do, since we're in the class for a single baseball player.  You
    // could create a class that contains a list of baseball players, but
    // why not just use a List by itself, as I've done.
    public String getBaseballPlayer(int i) {
        return getAsJSON();
    }

    // Turn a list of BaseballPlayer objects into a list of Strings
    public static List<String> playersToStrings(List<BaseballPlayer> players) {
        List<String> r = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BaseballPlayer player : players) {
            r.add(player.getAsJSON());
        }
        return r;
    }

    // Turn a list of Strings into a list of BaseballPlayer objects
    public static List<BaseballPlayer> stringsToPlayers(List<String> playerStrings) {
        List<BaseballPlayer> r = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String playerString : playerStrings) {
            try {
                BaseballPlayer player = mapper.readValue(playerString, BaseballPlayer.class);
                r.add(player);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        // Create a list of BaseballPlayer objects and print them
        List<BaseballPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(new BaseballPlayer("Joe", "Boston", "MA", 25, 6.1, "First Base"));
        players.add(new BaseballPlayer("Sam", "San Francisco", "CA", 28, 5.8, "Pitcher"));
        players.add(new BaseballPlayer("Kelly", "Chicago", "IL", 32, 6.4, "Catcher"));
        System.out.println(players);

        // Convert the list to a list of Strings and print the list
        List<String> playerStrings = playersToStrings(players);
        System.out.println(playerStrings);

        // Convert the Strings back into BaseballPlayer objects and print them
        players = stringsToPlayers(playerStrings);
        System.out.println(players);
    }

}
```

and here's the resulting output:

```
[Name: Joe from Boston, MA (height: 6.1), Name: Sam from San Francisco, CA (height: 5.8), Name: Kelly from Chicago, IL (height: 6.4)]
[{"hometown":"Boston","name":"Joe","state":"MA","position":"First Base","age":25,"height":6.1}, {"hometown":"San Francisco","name":"Sam","state":"CA","position":"Pitcher","age":28,"height":5.8}, {"hometown":"Chicago","name":"Kelly","state":"IL","position":"Catcher","age":32,"height":6.4}]
[Name: Joe from Boston, MA (height: 6.1), Name: Sam from San Francisco, CA (height: 5.8), Name: Kelly from Chicago, IL (height: 6.4)]
```

Here, each player is turned into JSON individually.  A few more lines of code, and you could turn an array of Baseball Player objects into a single String.

If this JSON-only solution isn't good enough for you, check out Gson.  It can preserve all Java types.  It just takes a bit more setup to describe how each of your objects should be turned into JSON and back.